# Generate Stats/Report by Count per day by monthly

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, fullcalendar

I was hoping to create a simple calendar. Generate count of entries by encoder daily and viewed in calendar style. Like January, February, etc.. or display entire year by month.

```
database have date_added and encoder columns
```

I have problem on putting it on one piece. I was hoping to find one. But no luck.

Like this style:
http://i599.photobucket.com/albums/tt79/emcevo/calendarreportviewproject_zps1445f4c8.jpg

I got this code: but this is not I wanted:

```
// SIX (6) DAYS AGO
$query = "SELECT COUNT(date_added) FROM `tbl_dv` WHERE `encodedby` = '".$_SESSION['name']."' AND DATE(date_added) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 DAY"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<font size='3'><b>[ ". $row['COUNT(date_added)'] ." ]</b></font> ENTRIES";
}

// FIVE (5) DAYS AGO
etc...
```

I want to have like the link above.. I have problem on implementing it in a true calendar format..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking how to count the encoders for each day something like this:

```
SELECT `date_added`, sum(`encoder`) as `daily_total` FROM `tableName` GROUP BY `date_added`;
```

Likewise for the monthly:

```
SELECT month(`date_added`) as month, sum(`encoder`) as dailytotal FROM `tableName` GROUP BY  month(`date_added`) ;
```

I would recommend a WHERE clause to limit to the year you wish to display

After that you would need to loop the results and build the calendar HTML. Many people find that a table works well for layout of such things. A number of classes exist to make generating them easier if you do a search.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I was hoping to do this with the calendar view with it.. It should create a calendar code with the count encoded of the encoder display per day..

Comment: So what are you asking? I do not think I understand your question.

Comment: Ok. I like to have this sample output: http://i599.photobucket.com/albums/tt79/emcevo/calendarreportviewproject_zps1445f4c8.jpg

Comment: Yes, I saw that you had added that. What code have you got so far?